# How to set up a local proxy server?

Tags: php, iis-7, proxy, localhost

I have downloaded Glype PHP proxy script. I have put it up in the localhost. Now I want all application on my PC to access internet through the local proxy server. How do I do that?

I've tried changing the LAN setting in Google Chrome. I enabled the option `Use a proxy server for your LAN` and set the address to `http://localhost/glype-1.4.3/`. But it didn't work out.

I am IIS7 Server on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to Use a proxy server for LAN settings in Google Chrome, Glype PHP proxy script just provides a proxy service to users via a web browser, you just browse website then enter any website address to surf.

Comment: But I want Glype to be the default proxy for everything that is opened through the browser.

Comment: You have to use other software such as Hotspot Shield ,.. , Glype PHP proxy script just provides a proxy service to users via a web browser .

Answer (score 0):

First of all sir You need to install Linux or Unix based OS on your PC, they are the  best servers, then extract the glype scripts into homepage and configure apache to accept connections on your ip and be sure to use a static ip within your local network.